# Adding Variance \ Weights Information When Solving a Basis Pursuit Denoising Problem (BPDN)

Tags: matlab, statistics, optimization, convex-optimization, sparse-model

Having a "measured" vector $\mathbf{y}$ with its statistics (counts or variance per element), one can use weighted least squares approach to solve the linear system $$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{y}$$ by minimizing $$(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x})^T{\rm diag}(\mathbf{c})(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}),$$ where $\mathbf{c}$ contains either counts or inverse variances.

When this linear problem is ill-posed but the model is sparse I can use the [Basis Pursuit Denoising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_pursuit_denoising) approach looking for a sparse solution:
$$ \mathbf{x}^{\ast} = \arg \min_{\mathbf{x}} \left\{ \frac{1}{2} {\left\| \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| \mathbf{x} \right\|}_{1} \right\} $$

Logically i am tempted to just modify the $\mathbf{A}$ term to $\mathbf{A}^T  {\rm diag}(\mathbf{c}) \mathbf{A}$ to include the weights for each element, but I am not sure this is a sound approach for the $L_1$ case. Is this approach valid or is there a different way to include the measurement statistic for such regularization?

Comment: Why can't you just replace ${\left\| \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2}$ with the term using $\mathbf{c}$? It just changes the problem to a weighted least squares.

Comment: that is what I ask more or less... I am not sure it makes sense.

Comment: I think it would relate to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30147.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formulation:

$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{1} $$

Has 2 elements:

1. The Fidelity Term
   This is basically measurements term with the model of AWGN with IID noise.
2. The Regularization Term
   This is a sparse promoting model by using the [Laplace Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) as a prior.

Since your measurement model is not IID but with different variance per measurement what you need is use [Mahalanobis Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) in the measurement model (Which matches the [Multivariate Gaussian Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)).

Using some variation of the norm (See [Norm with Symmetric Positive Definite Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011563/norm-with-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix)) which is defined as:

$$ {\left\| \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{W}^{2} = \boldsymbol{x}^{T} W \boldsymbol{x}, \; \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, W \in \mathbb{S}_{++}^{n} $$

You may formulate your problem as:

$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{ {C}^{-1} }^{2} + \lambda {\left\| \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{1} $$

Where $ C $ is your covariance matrix (Basically $ \operatorname{diag} \left( \boldsymbol{c} \right) $ on your question).
The above is easy to solve using many methods as it is basically transformed LS by using [Cholesky Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) of the Covariance Matrix.

Comment: I am trying to understand if I can articulate your answer in CVX (does adding weight render the problem to be non-convex?)... First, if I understand correctly the norm to be minimized $C^{-1}$ is the inverse(?) of the covariance matrix given by $C= (y−Ax)^T diag(c) (y−Ax)$ ?and to obtain the inverse I can use Cholesky Decomposition or etc?

Comment: @bla Adding the weighting does not make the problem non-convex.

Comment: @bla, Since $ {C}^{-1} = \operatorname{diag} \left( \boldsymbol{c}^{-1} \right) $ you can easily define $ {C}^{-1} $ and use `quad_form()` from `CVX`. You may mark this as answered and open a question specifically how to solve my form in CVX and I will post code.

Comment: @Royi, thank you will do.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/79087/cvx-for-covariance-matrix-norm