# Solving a Weighted Basis Pursuit Denoising Problem (BPDN) with MATLAB / CVX

Tags: matlab, denoising, convex-optimization, sparse-model, norm

Following up from an answer by @Royi on adding [weights to BPDN problem](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/79065/adding-variance-weights-information-when-solving-a-basis-pursuit-denoising-pro) , I would like to use CVX to test this approach.  How can we formulate in CVX the regularized LS L1 norm  with weights given by a vector $c$, as follows:
$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{ {C}^{-1} }^{2} + \lambda {\left\| \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{1} $$

Where $ C $ is the covariance matrix   $ \operatorname{diag} \left( \boldsymbol{c} \right) $  ?

Here's a minimal example using Matlab:

```
% problem data
A  = [1    0    0   0.5;...
      0    1  0.2   0.3;...
      0  0.1    1   0.2];
x0 = [1 0 1 0]';    % original signal
y  = A*x0;          % measurements with no noise
w  = randi(1e3,1,numel(y))'; % random weights vector
y  = y +  1./(sqrt(w)).*randn(numel(y),1); % measurements with weighted noise
```

CVX that does not include the weights info would be:

```
lambda = 0.01;      % regularization parameter
cvx_precision high
cvx_solver  SeDuMi
cvx_begin quiet
    variable x(size(A,2),1);
    minimize(norm(A*x-y)+lambda*norm(x1,1))
cvx_end 

x =
    0.9864
   -0.0281
    1.0108
         0
```

Comment: Could you share the data you have or an example of the data? Or a MATLAB script to generate it?

Comment: I added a minimal example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MATLAB code which implements the problem as defined and solve it using `CVX` is given by:

````
%% General Parameters
close('all');
clear('all');

%% Simulation Parameters
numRows = 6;
numCols = 10;

varianceFctr    = 3;
paramLambda     = 2.75;

%% Generate Data
mA  = randn(numRows, numCols);
vX0 = rand(numCols, 1) >= 0.65;
vC  = varianceFctr * rand(numRows, 1);

mCInv = diag(1 ./ vC);

vY = (mA * vX0) + (sqrt(vC) .* randn(numRows, 1));

%% Solving by CVX
cvx_begin('quiet')
    % cvx_precision('best');
    variable vX(numCols);
    minimize( 0.5 * quad_form(mA * vX - vY, mCInv) + (paramLambda * norm(vX, 1)) );
cvx_end
```
````

Comment: I dont have InitScript.m is that important? is `mCInv` similar to `1./(sqrt(w))` in my example?

Comment: I removed the need for `InitScript.m`. `vC` is the vector of variances. Hence the noise added is by it. In order to create the inverse of the matrix $  C $ I just used the inverse of each value (As it is a diagonal matrix).

Comment: maybe I dont understand from your code,  the noiseless signal mA * vX0 and the noisy signal vY , but you solve for vX so should I compare vX to vX0 ? (because the values there are not close)

Comment: Yes, `vX0` is the reference and `vX` is the solution. They are not close even in the case `vC = 1` as the issue is with the sparse reconstruction. But the question is about solving the problem, not if the sparse model solution is perfect.